# How to create a tabular file?

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'have.01':[':arg0',':arg1'], 'give.01':[':arg1',':arg2'], ':create.01':[':arg3', ':arg4']}
```

I need to generate the following file:

```
have.01, 1, 1, 0, 0
give.01, 0, 1, 1, 0
create.01, 0, 0, 1, 1
```

That is if the `:argX` is present, I put `1`.

I have no idea how to program this.

Comment: Do you accept pandas?

Comment: Yes. I accept..

Comment: It is better aadd pandas tag :-)

Answer (score 1):

By using pandas `get_dummies`

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.apply(','.join,1).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[29]: 
            :arg0  :arg1  :arg2  :arg3  :arg4
:create.01      0      0      0      1      1
give.01         0      1      1      0      0
have.01         1      1      0      0      0
```

Or we using (`stack` or `melt`)+ (`crosstab` or `pivot`)

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d).stack()
df
Out[33]: 
0  :create.01    :arg3
   give.01       :arg1
   have.01       :arg0
1  :create.01    :arg4
   give.01       :arg2
   have.01       :arg1
dtype: object
pd.crosstab(df.index.get_level_values(1),df)
Out[34]: 
col_0       :arg0  :arg1  :arg2  :arg3  :arg4
row_0                                        
:create.01      0      0      0      1      1
give.01         0      1      1      0      0
have.01         1      1      0      0      0
```

Comment: ValueError: arrays must all be the same length